# Primefaces - Custom Pagination/ Sorting load() issue

Tags: datatable, primefaces

We are using Primefaces 3.0.RC2 in our application with seam faces and CDI. We have followed the lazy loaded data table implementation on the component showcase. Since we have a large dataset, we have overridden the load() method to fetch only pagewise results. (vs loading all records in memory at once).

The pagination works as expected, however the sorting does not. The records get sorted correctly the first time the column header is clicked. For all subsequent clicks, the load() method is called twice, sending different values for the sorting order as a result of which, the sort order remains the same on the table. It seems like both the load() calls are being made in the APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES phase.

Can anyone provide any inputs as to why this is happening and how it can be avoided. Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Some additional info:
As stated earlier, we have overriden the load() method and have it actually query the DB to fetch sorted results pagewise (by specifying max results and order by in the query) and it works fine.

```
@Override
public List<ABC> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder
sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters)
{
    // Fetch data pagewise from the database
    datasource = dao.findPagewiseSortedResults(sortField,
            SortOrder.ASCENDING == sortOrder ? true : false, first, pageSize);

    // Set the row count
    this.setRowCount((int) dao.findTotalCount());

    return datasource;
}
```

However, on clicking the column on the datamodel for sorting, 2 post requests are made.

Find below the xhtml code:

```
        <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="record"
        value="#{testBean.lazyModel}" paginator="true" rows="5"
        paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport}           {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
        selectionMode="single" selection="#{testBean.selectedRecord}"
        sortBy="#{record.username}">

        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{testBean.onRowSelect}"
            update=":form:display" oncomplete="accountDialog.show()" />

        <p:ajax event="colResize" update=":form:growl"
            listener="#{testBean.onResize}" />

        <p:column sortBy="#{record.username}"
            filterBy="#{record.username}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="User Name" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{record.username}" />
        </p:column>.........

        </dataTable>
```

We have even upgraded to the latest Primefaces version (3.0.1) but it hasn't helped. Are we missing anything? Any pointers would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: I use 3.0 Final with Lazy Loading, filtering and sorting, but cannot see this behaviour. Even if it were present such bug (but is not), you could always read the sortOrder field and act consequently. Maybe it's better if you post some code

Comment: @perissf,Thanks for you reply. I have added some code to the original question. Please let me know if you need any more information/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are providing the sorting by use of the load() method, you don't have to use dataTable's native sorting tool. You need to remove the `sortBy` attribute from `p:dataTable` tag.

The component should be defined this way:

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="record"
    value="#{testBean.lazyModel}" paginator="true" rows="5"
    paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport}           {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
    selectionMode="single" selection="#{testBean.selectedRecord}" >
```

---

EDIT

This way, you'll have your column sortable exactly in the order specified by the client: you will read the SortOrder specified, with the Java code you have posted, and you will use that SortOrder consequently in your implementation of dao#findPagewiseSortedResults()

Comment: Thanks again perissf. But wouldn't this mean that the records will always be sorted in the order i specify in my database query. How will i provide the user with the option of sorting them in asc/desc order. I mean to keep the columns sortable and depending on the sort order specified, the order by clause in the query is applied. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Not sure to understand what you are asking

Comment: I thought u asked to delete sortBy attributes from the columns too. Sorry about the confusion. I deleted the sortBy attribute from datatable. The results are sorted & fetched from DB in asc order correctly. However, on clicking a column to reverse sorting order, it reverses the order correctly once and thereafter always remains sorted in desc order (no matter how many times i click). I see that it sends an asc sortorder to the backend (first load() call) but that is followed & overriden immediately by desc sort order(second load() call) and it seems like no sorting happened. Any leads?

Comment: I just don't understand why the load() method should be called twice.

Comment: Print the sortOrder each time load() is invoked, to check if the method is effectively invoked twice, or if your dao#findPagewiseSortedResults() is not behaving like desired

Comment: The load() is definitely called twice (confirmed in the logs and i see 2 post requests in firebug). I also the printed the query in the dao and that is perfectly fine. Basically, the sort will work if the second load() call is not made.